# Add blank value for key if does not exist when appending dictionaries to list

Tags: python

I have the following code which uses an API to download data from a website.

```
url = "https://gtr.ukri.org/project"
params = {"page": 11,
          "fetchSize": 100}
projects = requests.get(url,
                        params=params,
                        headers={"accept": "application/json"}).json()['projectsBean']['project']

for project in projects:
    list_projects.append({'ref': project['grantReference'], 'funder': project['fund']['funder']['name'],
                          'title': project['title'], 'category': project['grantCategory'],
                          'abstract': project['abstractText'], 'funding': project['fund']['valuePounds'],
                          'start': project['fund']['start'], 'end': project['fund']['end']})
```

This is working fine, however sometimes there is no `value` for a `key` when iterating through all the pages in the website (the `key` will always exist).

When this happens, it errors as a value is not there.

How do I `append` a `dictionary` to a `list` and just leave any values for any `key` blank if it does not exist, rather than erroring?

Many thanks

Comment: You may need [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a default value when no value exists in your dictionary you can do it like this

```
project.get('grantReference', 'no-ref')
```

the string `'no-ref'` is a default value if the project dict doesn't contain any key named grantReference.

the above is only an example to do get a value of dict with key without error.

but however, on your question

> This is working fine, however sometimes there is no value for a key when iterating through all the pages in the website (the key will always exist).

you doesn't mention the exact code line where the error come from so I can not help to create a complete example code.

For nested dictionary you can use the method like this

```
project.get('fund', {}).get('start', 0)
```

the first key `'fund'` will return value that you expecting or will default to be an empty dictionary. so the second key `'start'` will get value with key `'start'` from the dictionary you expecting or from the default empty dictionary we provide. (and we provide default value for key `'start'` which is the 0)

Comment: Thank you Fran. Just looking at .get now :)

Comment: Hi Fran, it is in the list.append part where the error is occurring. For example, on page 11, there is a project with no value for ['fund']['end']. But technically any value could be blank for any key (most will be populated though.

Comment: On your example (which works for grantReference), how does it work for nested dictionaries? I.e.  how would one do the 'funding' variable which is  ['fund']['valuePounds']?

Comment: Ah, I have got that working with pydash. Perfect. It is all working now :D

Comment: I update the answer. If my all answer can help you, please mark it as answer @Nicholas

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to override the `__missing__` operator on `dict` and use an object_hook on `json.loads` on your response string, which will work up to one level.

```
import json

class GetItemNone(dict):

    def __missing__(self, key):
        return None


example = """{
    "foo": {
        "bar": 1
    }
}"""


d = json.loads(example, object_hook=GetItemNone)
```

Examples:

```
d["foo"]["bar"] -> 1
d["foo"]["foo"] -> None
d["bar"] -> None
```

Comment: Thank you. I have got it working now, but will try your example in a bit to see if it works once my code has stopped running :)

Comment: @Nicholas This method doesnt work for `d["bar"]["foo"]` but im just trying to work away around that now

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach is what you are looking for:

```py
from functools import reduce

def get_object(obj, key):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if key in list(obj.keys()):
            return obj[key]
        else: 
            return ""
    else:
        return ""

projects =[{'grantReference': 'my_ref', 'fund':{'funder':{'name': "my_name"},
                                   'valuePounds': 25}}, 
           {'grantReference': 'my_ref', 'fund':{'start': "today",
                                   'end': "tomorrow"}}]
    
list_projects = []
for project in projects:
    list_projects.append({'ref': reduce(get_object, ['grantReference'], project),
                          'funder': reduce(get_object,['fund', 'funder', 'name'], project),
                          'title': reduce(get_object, ['title'], project), 
                          'category': reduce(get_object,  ['grantCategory'], project),
                          'abstract': reduce(get_object, ['abstractText'], project), 
                          'funding': reduce(get_object, ['fund', 'valuePounds'], project),
                          'start': reduce(get_object, ['fund', 'start'], project), 
                          'end': reduce(get_object, ['fund', 'end'], project)})



list_projects
```

output:

```
[{'ref': 'my_ref',
  'funder': 'my_name',
  'title': '',
  'category': '',
  'abstract': '',
  'funding': 25,
  'start': '',
  'end': ''},
 {'ref': 'my_ref',
  'funder': '',
  'title': '',
  'category': '',
  'abstract': '',
  'funding': '',
  'start': 'today',
  'end': 'tomorrow'}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lucas. I have got it working from Toms response, but will try yours once my code has stopped running to confirm :)

Comment: No problem, I think the answer from Tom is very nice